# Flutter Video Compression with ffmpeg_kit_flutter: PathNotFoundException Error

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to compress videos using the ffmpeg_kit_flutter library in Flutter. However, I've encountered an issue where the compression fails, and I receive the following error message:

> Video compression failed. Error: PathNotFoundException: Cannot retrieve length of file

Here is the relevant code for my video compression function:

```
Future<File?> compressVideo(File file) async {
 final name = basenameWithoutExtension(file.path);
 final epoch = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
 final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
 Directory directory = await Directory(join(temp.path, 'video')).create();
 final outputPath = [directory.path, '${name}_$epoch.mp4']
     .join(Platform.pathSeparator);
 final ffmpegCommand = '-i ${file.path} -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset veryfast ${outputPath}';
 try {
   await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(ffmpegCommand);
   print('Video compression completed successfully');
   return File(outputPath);
 } catch (e) {
   print('Video compression failed. Error: ${e.toString()}');
   return null;
 }
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this "PathNotFoundException" error. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can fix it? I want to successfully compress videos using ffmpeg_kit_flutter in my Flutter app.